# how to null a particular byte in an xmm register?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, sse

I want to know if there is a simple efficient way of doing the following

given:

```
sample       db   'hello worldxxxxx'
sample_len   db   11
```

I want to:

```
movdqa xmm0, [sample]
; here I want to put a zero in the 11th byte of xmm0 (11 coming from [sample_len].
; I don't want to modify the original data.
```

The bytes higher than `[sample_len]` can be zeroed or not, doesn't matter.  I know I can do it with half a dozen sse instructions and/or using `pcmpestrm` etc but I'm hoping there's a much simpler more efficient way.  It seems like such a simple commonplace requirement, I'm surprised if there isn't a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

If the size is known at compile time, you can use a couple of shift instructions like so:

```
PSLLDQ xmm0, (16 - 11) * 8
PSRLDQ xmm0, (16 - 11) * 8
```

You could also use the `PAND` instruction. However, that requires another 128 bit number:

```
; if in a loop, you would pre-load the mask in a register
MOVDQA xmm1, [mask]
PAND xmm0, xmm1

; if one time event, directly access memory
PAND xmm0, [mask]
```

You could build the mask on the stack if you need to define it dynamically. Just make sure it is properly aligned...

Comment: Why `andpd`? It works, but it's neither the shortest instruction (that's `andps`) nor the "usually best" instruction, `pand`, which has a better throughput on some µarchs

Comment: The location of the byte to be zeroed is not known at compile time.  Would be great if I could create a mask with a single instruction using a value in a register to pick the byte to be zeroed

Comment: One possible way is to have 16 masks and load  the one corresponding to your needs...

Comment: You could use a sliding window with one `0xFF` byte and 15 `0` bytes on either side.  Significantly more efficient than 16 separate 16B constants.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think that won't work because SSE requires data that you load to be 16 bytes aligned.

Comment: `movups`/`movdqu` has no penalty on modern CPUs when it doesn't cross a cache-line boundary.